# How can I add more swatches and gradients to a swatch library?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, color, swatches, palette

I've created a color scheme on [Adobe Color](https://color.adobe.com) web page and exported it to use on Illustrator (let's name it as "my custom palette"), now I have one more color and one gradient I'd like to add to that library, which I've exported from adobe color to an ASE file. I already tried to click, hold and drag to "my custom palette", but it didn't work. Also, after I defined that swatch palette, I will need to put it into Photoshop.

I know this question may be some of an "idiot" one to experts, but I'm not a one, and with your help maybe I became a one :)

Comment: can you use more than five colours in a theme on Adobe colours? It seems like all of the themes use only five.

Answer (score 0):

Can you load your new color palette, aply your new styles to an object, load the old Palette, select the object and add the style with create new swatch to the old palette?

Comment: I'll give a try!